# how to set timeout with stream_socket_client and STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT

Tags: php, sockets, asynchronous, timeout, asyncsocket

I've been looking at this for an hour or so with no real luck.

Running PHP 5.4.45 (don't say it, I know).

In a production instance I'm seeing that a socket connection periodically fails with a timeout after 5 seconds. We have confirmed the API we're connecting to can sometimes take up to 10 seconds to generate a response for some requests.

This does not consistently happen, so we're looking into increasing the timeout to help debug the issue.

The socket is defined like

```
$address = 'tcp://example.com:80';
$flags = STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT;
$context = stream_context_create();

$socket = stream_socket_client($address, $errNr, $errMsg, 0, $flags, $context);
```

To test the connection timeout I tried setting the following to an insanely low timeout so that I could trigger the error and verify that increasing the timeout

```
$address = 'tcp://example.com:80';
$flags = STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT;
$context = stream_context_create();

$socket = stream_socket_client($address, $errNr, $errMsg, 0, $flags, $context);
stream_set_timeout($this->_socket, 0, 40);
```

However it's working just as it did before, if the timeout of 40 microseconds had been correctly applied then I would have expected the socket timeout error to occur locally as there is no way the API responded in that timeframe.

Can anyone help me out with how to properly configure the timeout for an asynchronous socket?

Or alternatively the current timeout it's clearly getting 5 seconds from somewhere but I don't know where as the `default_socket_timeout` is currently set to `60` in the php.ini.

Or if my testing methodology is bogus (as I suspect it may be) please point out a better way to verify this timeout error.